# How to convert an ADP to ACCDB using Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access-2013, adp

Access 2013 does not support ADP. Some alternatives to ADPs are given:

- Convert the ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database.
- Import objects into an ACCDE file and then create linked tables to the existing data by using an earlier version of Access.

My ADP contains only Forms, Reports, Macros and Modules. I want to use this ADP in Access 2013 (not on any earlier version of Access).

I have not found any method to convert ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database or to Import objects into an ACCDE file on Access 2013.

How can I convert an ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database or to Import objects into an ACCDE file using Access 2013?

Comment: ADP is still alive in Access 2013, I found this link:
http://www.joakimdalby.dk/HTM/ADPX.htm

Comment: Maybe thou also found something like $199 for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I convert an ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database or to Import objects into an ACCDE file using Access 2013?

You can't. Access 2013 won't work with ADP files **at all**. If you try to import objects from an ADP file in Access 2013, you get the following error:

[image: Access Data Projects are no longer supported in this version of Access.]

What you need to do is

- find a machine with Access 2010 or earlier,
- use it to import the Queries, Forms, etc., from the ADP into an `.accdb` or `.mdb` file, then
- take that `.accdb` or `.mdb` file back to your Access 2013 machine and continue on from there.

**edit re: comments**

> Is there is no way to Convert the ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database using access 2013

Apparently not. Even trying to use VBA to copy a Form object from an `.adp` file into an `.accdb` file fails. The following code:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub adpImportTest()
    Dim dbPath As String, formName As String
    On Error GoTo adpImportTest_Error

    Debug.Print "Try importing a form from an .accdb file..."
    dbPath = "C:\Users\Gord\Documents\accdbTest.accdb"
    formName = "myCustomers"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbPath, acForm, formName, formName
    Debug.Print "Import succeeded."

    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Try importing a form from an .adp file..."
    dbPath = "C:\Users\Gord\Documents\NorthwindCS.adp"
    formName = "Customers"
    DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", dbPath, acForm, formName, formName
    Debug.Print "Import succeeded."

    Exit Sub
adpImportTest_Error:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

...produces the following result:

```
Try importing a form from an .accdb file...
Import succeeded.

Try importing a form from an .adp file...
The search key was not found in any record.
```

If we try to get sneaky and rename the `.adp` file to `.mdb` then Access 2013 won't read it:

[image: Unrecognized database format]

As I said, you need to use Access 2010 (or older) to extract the objects from the `.adp` file into an `.accdb` or `.mdb` file. *Then* you can work with the `.accdb` or `.mdb` file in Access 2013.

Comment: Thanks Thompson for reply.Then what is meaning of ADP alternatives :
Convert the ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database.
Import objects into an ACCDE file and then create linked tables to the existing data by using an earlier version of Access.

Comment: Hi Thompson Is there is no way to Convert the ADP to a linked Access Desktop Database using access 2013.I want to convert ADP to Desktop Database and then import in my main database.or Can i read ADP forms reports etc programmatically and then insert in my main database using ADO if it possible plz tell me.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using office<2013 eg 2010 2007

Try using save as text / load from text to transfer forms
You can then edit the text files preparing recordsources for your accdb linked tables.

Partial and uncleaned code but gives you an idea

module LoadSaveForm:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Base 0
Option Explicit

Dim path$
Dim DateTimeString$
Dim app As Access.Application



Function SaveFormAsText(FormName As String) As Boolean
  Dim sPath As String
  Access.SaveAsText acForm, FormName, "C:\Temp" & "\" & FormName & ".txt"
End Function

Function LoadFormFromText(FormName As String)
  Access.LoadFromText acForm, FormName, "C:\Temp" & "\" & FormName & ".txt"
End Function

Private Sub SaveMDBObjectsAsText()

    DateTimeString = Format(Now(), "yyyymmddhhnn")
    path = CurrentProject.path & "\" '& "AS_TEXT_" & DateTimeString & "\"

    If Dir(path) <> "" Then
        'It exists
    Else
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir path
        On Error GoTo 0

    End If

    SaveDataAccessPagesAsText
    SaveFormsAsText
    SaveReportsAsText
    SaveModulesAsText
    'SaveQueriesAsText
    CreateProjectFromText (path)

End Sub


Public Sub CreateProjectFromText(pathString As String)
    path = pathString
    'SaveMDBBase
    SaveAccdbDBase
    LoadDataAccessPagesFromText
    LoadFormsFromText
    LoadReportsFromText
    LoadModulesFromText
    'LoadQueriesFromText
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim r As Reference
    With app
        With .CurrentProject
            path = .FullName
        End With

        For Each r In .References
            With r
                If Not .BuiltIn Then
                    app.References.Remove r
                End If
            End With
        Next r

        For Each r In References
            With r
                If Not .BuiltIn Then
                    app.References.AddFromGuid r.GUID, r.Major, r.Minor
                End If
            End With
        Next r
        .RunCommand acCmdSaveAllModules
        .RunCommand acCmdCompileAndSaveAllModules
        .CloseCurrentDatabase
        .SysCmd 603, path, Replace(Replace(Replace(path, ".accdb", ".accde"), ".adp", ".ade"), ".mdb", ".mde")
        .Quit
    End With
    Set app = Nothing
    MsgBox "All Done with Text Backup"

End Sub

Private Sub SaveDataAccessPagesAsText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim DataAccessPage As AccessObject
    For Each DataAccessPage In CurrentProject.AllDataAccessPages
        Name = DataAccessPage.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        SaveAsText acDataAccessPage, Name, filename
    Next DataAccessPage
End Sub

Private Sub SaveFormsAsText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim Form As AccessObject
    For Each Form In CurrentProject.AllForms
        Name = Form.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        SaveAsText acForm, Name, filename
    Next Form
End Sub

Private Sub SaveReportsAsText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim Report As AccessObject
    For Each Report In CurrentProject.AllReports
        Name = Report.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        SaveAsText acReport, Name, filename
    Next Report
End Sub

Private Sub SaveMacrosAsText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim Macro As AccessObject
    For Each Macro In CurrentProject.AllMacros
        Name = Macro.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        SaveAsText acMacro, Name, filename
    Next Macro
End Sub

Private Sub SaveModulesAsText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim Module As AccessObject
    For Each Module In CurrentProject.AllModules
        Name = Module.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        SaveAsText acModule, Name, filename
    Next Module
End Sub

Private Sub SaveQueriesAsText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim GetQueryNames As ADODB.Recordset
    Set GetQueryNames = CurrentProject.connection.OpenSchema(adSchemaViews)
    With GetQueryNames
        Do While Not .EOF
            Name = .Fields("TABLE_NAME")
            filename = path & Name & ".txt"
            SaveAsText acQuery, Name, filename
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Private Function SaveAccdbDBase() As Database
    Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    'Get default Workspace
    Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Name = Replace(CurrentProject.Name, CurrentProject.path, "")
    If Name Like "*.adp" Then
        Name = Replace(Name, "adp", "accdb")
    Else
        Name = Replace(Name, "accdb", "adp")
  End If
    filename = path & Name
 'Make sure there isn't already a file with the name of the new database
   If Dir(filename) <> "" Then Kill filename

   Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
   'Create a new mdb file
   If Name Like "*.adp" Then
        Application.CreateAccessProject filename, getConnection.ConnectionString
    Else
    Set db = ws.CreateDatabase(filename, dbLangGeneral)
    End If
   db.Close
   Set db = Nothing
    'SaveAsText 6, "", filename
    If Name Like "*.adp" Then

        app.Visible = True
        app.UserControl = True
        app.OpenAccessProject filename
    Else
        app.OpenCurrentDatabase filename
    End If
    app.SetOption "Show Navigation Pane Search Bar", True
    Set SaveAccdbDBase = db
End Function

Private Sub LoadDataAccessPagesFromText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim DataAccessPage As AccessObject
    For Each DataAccessPage In CurrentProject.AllDataAccessPages
        Name = DataAccessPage.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        app.LoadFromText acDataAccessPage, Name, filename
    Next DataAccessPage
End Sub

Private Sub LoadFormsFromText()
    Dim filename$
    Dim Name$
    Dim Form As AccessObject
    For Each Form In CurrentProject.AllForms
        Name = Form.Name
        filename = path & Name & ".txt"
        On Error Resume Next
        app.LoadFromText acForm, Name, filename
    Next Form
End Sub

Sub CreateNewMDBFile()

   Dim ws As Workspace
   Dim db As Database
   Dim LFilename As String

   'Get default Workspace
   Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)

   'Path and file name for new mdb file
   LFilename = "c:\NewDB.mdb"

   'Make sure there isn't already a file with the name of the new database
   If Dir(LFilename) <> "" Then Kill LFilename

   'Create a new mdb file
   Set db = ws.CreateDatabase(LFilename, dbLangGeneral)

   'For lookup tables, export both table definition and data to new mdb file
   DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", LFilename, acTable, "Lookup Table1", "Lookup Table1", False

   'For data entry tables, export only table definition to new mdb file
   DoCmd.TransferDatabase acExport, "Microsoft Access", LFilename, acTable, "DataEntry Table1", "DataEntry Table1", True

   db.Close
   Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Run SaveMDBObjectsAsText() to get an idea of what happens

Comment: there's a more complete implementation of this at https://github.com/timabell/msaccess-vcs-integration